# Python - PySimpleGUI - Programa dando erro ao ser terminado

Tags: python, gui, runtime

Olá, pessoal!
Sou novato na programação e estou estudando Python há algumas semanas.
Estou trabalhando em um programa que basicamente, pega um preço qualquer que você digite (em Reais) e aplica uma porcentagem a mais de acordo com duas opções definidas em um menu e o retorna atualizado em um Output. A sua interface gráfica foi criada usando a biblioteca PySimpleGUI.

O programa roda perfeitamente. Porém, ao ser fechado, o PyCharm acusa: Process finished with exit code 1

Ao convertê-lo para exe, o programa é executado corretamente, porém, ao ser fechado, aparece um erro em uma caixa escrito "Failed to execute script taxa.py" e ao passá-lo para um outro computador, ele nem chega a abrir, apenas aparece esse erro.

Sei que o código está longe de ser o perfeito, porém, gostaria de saber o que devo fazer para ele funcionar corretamente.

A versão do Python que utilizo é a 3.8

Aqui está o código do programa:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from decimal import Decimal
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')


sg.theme('DefaultNoMoreNagging')

class Tela:

    def __init__(self):

        # Layout
        layout = [
            [sg.OptionMenu(values=[
                "Taxa 1",
                "Taxa 2"],
                key='opcoes', size=(27, 0), pad=(15, 10))],
            [sg.Text('Digite o valor a ser calculado:', pad=(30, 0))],
            [sg.Input(key='valordigitado', size=(40, 0), pad=(0, 10))],
            [sg.Button('Calcular', pad=(80, 0), bind_return_key=True, size=(30,0))],
            [sg.Output(size=(30,20), key='output')]

        ]
        # Janela
        self.janela = sg.Window('Aplicadora de taxas',
                                size=(250, 460)).layout(layout)

    def iniciar(self):
        
        taxa01 = 1.15
        taxa02 = 1.30
        
        while True:
            # Extrair os dados da tela
            self.button, self.values = self.janela.Read()

            opcoes = self.values['opcoes']
            valordigitado = self.values['valordigitado']

            self.janela['output'].Update('')
            
            if ',' in valordigitado:
                if '.' in valordigitado:
                    valordigitado = valordigitado.replace('.', '')
                valordigitado = valordigitado.replace(',', '.')

            try:
                valordigitado = Decimal(valordigitado)

            except:
                print('Digite um número válido.')
                continue
            
            #Cálculo
            try:
                if opcoes == 'Taxa 1':
                    valordigitado = valordigitado * Decimal(taxa01)
                
                elif opcoes == 'Taxa 2':
                    valordigitado = valordigitado * Decimal(taxa02)

            except:
                print('Digite um número válido.')
                continue
            

            print(f'R$ {locale.format_string("%.2f", valordigitado, grouping=True)}')


Tela().iniciar()
```

Comment: Você escreveu o script com falta de configuração,eu vou mandar o código corrigido em breve.... E com explicação!
Também não precisa usar class em PySimpleGUI,não obrigatório o uso de POO .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo migrar do pysimplegui para o kivy. É igualmente simples e rápido para criar interfaces sem estresse, mas melhor em vários aspectos.Também encontrei erros sem solução no pysimplegui e achei mais simples usar o kivy. https://python.libhunt.com/compare-pysimplegui-vs-kivy

Answer (score 0):

O erro mais crítico foi a falta do comando:

```
   if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

Esse comando fecha a janela no (X) sem da erro!

Também não vai na onda desse outro cara aí,kivy é bem mais complexo e ele faz a mesma coisa do que o PySimpleGUI,mas com kivy gera um APK no linux com buildozer. O cara já sabe programar pelo jeito, então eu recomendo que você use PySimpleGUI,pelo oque eu vi no seu código você recém conheceu a lib ou não leu a documentação ou é novo 4 meses no máximo em python não é?